# How to invoke listeners using cucumber?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-junit

This is my Junit runner file with cucumber. I want to invoke listners here but dont know how to do this.

```
package com.olmgroup.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format={"pretty","junit:reports/junit/junit.xml",      
 "html:reports/html", 


 "json:reports/json/integration_report.json","junit:reports/xml/cucumber.xml"}, 
                      features="src/test/resources/integration.feature", dryRun=false, glue="com.olmgroup.script",
                      tags="@IntegrationTesting")

public class IntegrationRunner{

}
```

Comment: what kind of listeners? Can you explain your use case?

Comment: I want to invoke listener which generate custom report after execution are done.

Comment: In the steps definitions class you can use `@After` annotation, it will be called after your scenario.

Comment: but there would be lots of step definitions class and this listener generate report which I want to run after execution done and cucumber generate its report.